# Дух слишком интересуется историей

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, дух-сообщества, блокировка

Обнаружил, что Дух поднимает вопросы с исторической блокировкой. Во-первых, зачем он это делает? А во-вторых, куда он их поднимает? Они же не отображаются на главной.

Далее, пока я собирался написать этот вопрос, оказалось, что дух поднял [тот же исторический вопрос](/q/2775/178988) второй раз [подряд](/posts/2775/revisions). Это уже вообще странно. Неужели старых вопросов мало, и приходится поднимать одни и те же?

[image: В избранном вопрос помечен как изменённый]

[image: Но историческую блокировку он получил раньше]

[image: Что видно в истории]

Answer (score 3):

Логика поднятия вопроса Духом сообщества выглядит [следующим образом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/274323).

Дух поднимает вопрос максимум один вопрос в час. Для поднятия вопрос должен:

- иметь рейтинг 0 и более;
- быть неактивным как минимум в течении 30 дней;
- иметь как минимум один не удаленный ответ с рейтингом 0;
- *не* иметь ответов, отмеченных принятыми;

Также вопрос не может быть заблокированным или закрытым.

Пожалуйста, учтите, что Дух сообщества поднимает вопросы, если утверждается анонимная предложенная правка.

Comment: Правок там быть не могло - там же историческая блокировка. Дух поднимает вопросы, чтобы привлечь к ним внимание. К закрытым - дано, но ведь с вопросами с исторической блокировкой это всё равно не выйдет, поскольку они не отображаются на главной. Т. е. куда он его поднял, если кроме как в избранном и в истории вопроса это увидеть невозможно? Явно же нелогичное поведение - можно было поднять что-то другое. Или я не прав и где-то поднятый вопрос всё-таки увидеть можно? Кстати, само по себе привлечение внимания к вопросу, с которым ничего невозможно сделать, тоже вызывает некоторые сомнения.

Comment: @Qwertiy В случае с утверждением правки от незарегистрированного участника, Дух не поднимает вопрос, он является автором правки, но сама правка поднимает (если я верно понял вопрос).

Comment: Неа. Я вроде вообще не об этом...

Comment: мне кажется, надо просто выключить его.

Comment: @zb' Просто выключить – не получится, это крайне важная механика сайта.

Comment: И чем она важна, что то я не заметил такой на английском so. По крайней мере не так чтобы  несколько раз в день некропост поднимался с некачественным вопросом.

Comment: @zb' Если я правильно помню, Дух поднимает старый вопрос, если в нем есть ответы с нулевым рейтингом. Основная задача – предложить участникам проголосовать за или против. То есть, если бы все вопросы содержали ответы либо с положительным рейтингом, либо с отрицательным, Дух ничего бы не поднимал.