# Удаление своих некачественных публикаций

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, удаление-ответов

Решил очистить профиль от некачественных публикаций, которые не несут никакой пользы сайту, после попытки удаления 6 ответа сайт выдал ошибку:
*Вы удалили 5 своих сообщений сегодня; дальнейшее удаление заблокировано. См. "[Я переосмыслил свой вопрос; как его удалить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)?", чтобы узнать об альтернативных решениях.*

Перехожу по ссылке, про ответы там мало чего написано, но есть описание про вопросы и так как я удалял ответ, думаю он не случайно меня сюда отправил:

> Если вы действительно не видите способов спасти свой вопрос путём удаления идентифицирующих деталей, и ни один из ответов не заплюсован, и, особенно, если вопрос был закрыт, вы можете использовать флаг, чтобы попросить модераторов удалить его.

Флага я естественно не нашел, но так как описано что я могу попросить модераторов произвести удаление, я установил тревоги на свой вопрос с просьбой об удалении ответа, но все тревоги вернулись с ответом:

> тревоги стоит использовать, только чтобы предупредить модераторов о необходимости их вмешательства

Что в данном случае я делаю не так и почему установлены такие ограничения, из за чего я не могу удалить более 5 ответов с нулевым рейтингом > 1месяца?

Comment: Потому что нечего удалять всё подряд.

Comment: @Qwertiy так не все подряд, а только низкокачественные ответы)

Comment: А мне вот кажется странной не сама блокировка удалений (лимит видимо на случай кражи аккаунта и зловредничества с ним) - а именно то, что на превышение лимита удаления **ответов** вылезает ссылка на справку про удаление **вопросов**. Нелогично как-то... тогда уж стоит поменять в тексте слово "вопрос" на "публикация", если у вопросов и ответов общие лимиты удаления.

Comment: \*Заменить слово - имею в виду, в тексте статьи из справки, конечно (а не в этом вопросе). Типа _«Вы, вполне вероятно, можете переосмыслить свой вопрос **или ответ** ... Если вы опубликовали какую-то чувствительную информацию (пароль, секретный ключ), отредактируйте **сообщение** и используйте флаг, чтобы попросить модераторов убрать их из истории правок ... »_, и т.д.. Там уже используется термин "сообщение": _«...чрезмерное удаление полезных сообщений может спровоцировать...»_

Comment: Любое действие должно иметь как минимум цель. Ещё желательно, чтобы от него была польза. Вы правда думаете, что удаление не сильно качественного ответа - полезно? почти наверняка там есть что-то, что отсутствует в других ответах, и что при определённых обстоятельствах может оказаться полезным третьему участнику, который найдёт поиском частично соответствующую его проблеме тему. Если Вас так волнует качество своего ответа - намного разумнее откорректировать его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нулевой рейтинг у ответа еще не означает, что ответ некачественный, и что его стоит удалять.

У многих посетителей вообще нет аккаунта на SO. На каждый плюс на ответе есть десятки/сотни посетителей, которым ответ оказался полезен, но которые просто не смогли или не захотели нажать плюс.

Бот периодически поднимает вопросы с ответами без плюсов на главную, и там регулярно встречаются хорошие ответы, которым просто не досталось плюсов.

Не стоит тратить время на удаление контента, который вполне может оказаться полезным, но которому просто не повезло поймать плюс :)

Comment: Мне уже и бан дали, правда оказалось, случайно) И все ответы восстановили) Поэтому пожалуй "подзабью" на это дело с удалением, пусть будет. Просто удивляет отсутствие возможности потереть записи даже с нулевым рейтингом и на тех вопросах где есть более качественный ответ

Comment: Поднимает, вроде как, не без плюсов, а если нет ответа с положительным рейтингом и [есть нулевой у одного из](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3329/176217). Кстати, [вопрос по изменению тематики сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2775/176217) регулярно поднимается Духом. Но видно это поднятие почему-то только в приложении SE, а на сайте не видно. Где-то об этом тоже была заметочка.

Comment: Ещё есть [статистика недооцененных/переоцененных сообщений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback/most-helpful?filter=all). Где видно сколько раз кликали up/down кнопки те, у кого нет на это права.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ да, идея как раз в том, чтобы подтолкнуть участников плюсануть ответ с нулевым рейтингом, если он не получил плюс когда-то давно. мне периодически прилетает +10 на старых ответах, про которые я уже давно забыл :)

Comment: Но вот когда ответ имеет итоговый 0, а по факту +10/-10, поднятие такого вопроса мне кажется сомнительным.

Answer (score 1):

Все вопросы и ответы здесь:

> предоставляются на условиях лицензии cc by-sa. rev 2021.8.5.39930

Описание разрешения можно посмотреть [здесь](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.ru). Из этого и надо исходить. При желании, могут и вообще запретить удаление сообщений.